# Получение названия столбцов через Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность получить название столбцов выгрузки SQL запроса в Hibernate?
Суть вопроса, есть веб-сервис отчетов, есть XML где хранятся запросы. Есть вывод на JSP
Сделал вот так

```
<c:if test="${!empty reportList}">
<table>
    <!--  <tr>
        <th><spring:message code="issuenum" /></th>
        <th><spring:message code="PROJECT" /></th>
        <th><spring:message code="SUMMARY" /></th>
        <th><spring:message code="CREATED" /></th>
    </tr>-->
    <c:forEach items="${reportList}" var="report">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="i" begin = "0" end = "${lenght}">
                <td>${report[i]}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Но мне так же надо сделать, чтобы получать динамически столбцы, это нужно для универсальности, чтобы можно было добавляться отчеты со странице, далее маппить с XML с запросами, чтобы избежать перекомпелирование warника. В XML будут прописываться хранимые процедуры в итоге, чтобы так же избежать создания сущностей таблиц.

Можно ли это как-то реализоваться или нет, все равно придется при добавлении ссылки+ запроса в XML что-то делать с warником?

Может кто-то так делал? Либо подсказать какое-нибудь иное решение. Но суть такая, чтобы пользователь мог сам себе добавить отчет нужный.

**UPDATE:**

Реализация через процедуры сделана для того, чтобы избежать JOINы и тд, так как в hibernate сложновато с этим, даже с тем же concate, чтобы сделать, нужно в сущности аннотация ставить

Запрос к БД

```
SELECT CONCAT(l.jiraissue.project_def.pkey, l.jiraissue.fullName2) as clmName, l.cwd_user.display_name, l.worklogbody, l.startdate, l.timeworked/3600 FROM worklog as l
```

Как мне получить имена полей, именно тех, которые в select и в таком же порядке, учитывая, что я использовал аннотацию join с таблицей cwd_user и jiraissue?

Класс-сущность

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "worklog")
public class worklog implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3754944057116773016L;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "issueid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private jiraissue jiraissue;

public jiraissue getJiraissue() {
    return jiraissue;
}

public void setJiraissue(jiraissue jiraissue) {
    this.jiraissue = jiraissue;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private cwd_user cwd_user;

public cwd_user getCwd_user() {
    return cwd_user;
}

public void setCwd_user(cwd_user cwd_user) {
    this.cwd_user = cwd_user;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "issueid")
private int issueid;

@Column(name = "AUTHOR")
private String author;

@Column(name = "worklogbody")
private String worklogbody;

@Column(name = "STARTDATE")
private Date startdate;

@Column(name = "timeworked")
private int timeworked;

геттеры и сеттеры
```

плюс еще 2 класса

Контроллер из которого и передаю в JSP

```
@Controller
public class ReportingServicesController {

@Autowired
private ReportingServicesService reportingServicesService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
    return "welcome";
}

private List<? extends Object> list = null;
private String nameRequest = null;
private String[] columns = null;

// Получения результата отчета
@RequestMapping(value = "/report", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String reportList(@RequestParam(value = "user", required = false, defaultValue = "") String user,
        @RequestParam(value = "request", required = false) String request,
        @RequestParam(value = "start", required = false, defaultValue = "") String start,
        @RequestParam(value = "end", required = false, defaultValue = "") String end, Map<String, Object> map) {
    // временная проверка
    if (user.equals("")) {
        list = reportingServicesService.listReport(request);
    } else {
        list = reportingServicesService.listReport(user, request, start, end);
        columns = reportingServicesService.getColumnNames();
    }

    nameRequest = request;
    // map.put("jiraissue", new jiraissue());
    map.put("reportList", list);
    map.put("lenght", reportingServicesService.getLenghtArrayList(list));
    map.put("columns", columns);
    return "reports";
}
```

DAOImpl Метод выполнения запроса, сам запрос берется из XML

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<? extends Object> listReport(String user, String nameRequest, String start, String end) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(ParserQueryXML.getQueryFromXML(nameRequest))
            .setString("user", user).setString("start", start).setString("end", end).list();
}
```

Сам JSP

```
<c:if test="${!empty reportList}">
<table>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="i" begin = "0" end = "${lenght}">
            <th><spring:message code="${columns[i]}" /></th>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${reportList}" var="report">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://jira.ru/browse/${report[0]}" target="_blank">${report[0]}</a></td>
            <c:forEach var="i" begin = "1" end = "${lenght}">
                <td>${report[i]}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Я мог все проще сделать, указать в ручную поля, но задача не кампилить и вообще не лазить в код. Я вроде все сделал, вот только с полями осталось(((

В дальнейшем все на процедуры переведу, чтобы и не создавать классы сущности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить поля сущности просто:

```
String[] columnNames = getSessionFactory()
                         .getClassMetadata(Report.class)
                         .getPropertyNames();
```

Получить поля из `List<Object[]>`, который возвращает метод [Query.list()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#list--) при явном перечислении полей в запросе без явного указания их маппинга на какой-то класс, невозможно, так как в списке массивов объектов просто негде хранить эту информацию.

Остаётся писать какой-то хэлпер, который будет извлекать из xml'ки не только запрос, но и список названий полей. Либо описывать для каждого запроса [DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO), возвращать его вместо массива и вызывать в шаблоне его метод, возвращающий список названий его полей:

```
public class SomeReportDTO {
    private final String clmName;
    private final String displayName;
    private final String worklogBody;
    private final Long startDate;
    private final Long timeWorked;

    public SomeReportDTO(String clmName, String displayName,
      String worklogBody, Long startDate, Long timeWorked) {
        this.clmName = clmName;
        ...
    }

    public String[] getFieldNames() {
        return new String[] {
            "Какое-то имя";
            "Дисплейное имя";
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, такой способ я видел, а что делать если у меня join'ы есть SELECT CONCAT(l.jiraissue.project_def.pkey, l.jiraissue.fullName2), l.cwd_user.display_name, l.worklogbody, l.startdate, l.timeworked/3600 FROM worklog as l WHERE. Мне то нужно вывести именно такие колонки, а не из одного класса сущности.

Comment: то есть имею ввиду, что он мне вывел все колонки [author, cwd_user, issueid, jiraissue, startdate, timeworked, worklogbody], в итоге у меня при построение отчета не совпали название и содержимое. А мне нужно именно, чтобы он выводил колонки, которые я запросил. Так можно сделать? т.е. чтобы он мне вывел [jiranum, cwd_user, workbody, startdate, timework] в таком именно порядке.

Comment: Ваш запрос с join'ами, что вам возвращает, список массивов объектов или список DTO?

Comment: немного не понял вопроса, он мне возвращает данные из БД, по полям, которые я указал в select, но запрос имен полей возвращает массив всех имен из класса worklog, и еще сортирует по имени.

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавьте код выборки из базы.

Comment: Вопрос отредактировал, добавил SQL запрос

Comment: Мне нужен не запрос, мне нужен полный код получения тех данных, которые вы потом передаёте в JSP.

Comment: Поместил код сущности, контроллер и сам jsp

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64957/discussion-between--and-sergey-gornostaev).

Comment: Спасибо большое, тогда проще наверно заводить имена полей при добавление отчета вместе с запросам на форме jsp, далее в xml передавать их. Такая мысль была, просто думал, что может есть проще способ.

Answer (score 0):

Класс-сущность

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "worklog")
public class worklog implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3754944057116773016L;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "issueid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private jiraissue jiraissue;

public jiraissue getJiraissue() {
    return jiraissue;
}

public void setJiraissue(jiraissue jiraissue) {
    this.jiraissue = jiraissue;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private cwd_user cwd_user;

public cwd_user getCwd_user() {
    return cwd_user;
}

public void setCwd_user(cwd_user cwd_user) {
    this.cwd_user = cwd_user;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "issueid")
private int issueid;

@Column(name = "AUTHOR")
private String author;

@Column(name = "worklogbody")
private String worklogbody;

@Column(name = "STARTDATE")
private Date startdate;

@Column(name = "timeworked")
private int timeworked;

геттеры и сеттеры
```

плюс еще 2 класса

Контроллер из которого и передаю в JSP

```
@Controller
public class ReportingServicesController {

@Autowired
private ReportingServicesService reportingServicesService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
    return "welcome";
}

private List<? extends Object> list = null;
private String nameRequest = null;
private String[] columns = null;

// Получения результата отчета
@RequestMapping(value = "/report", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String reportList(@RequestParam(value = "user", required = false, defaultValue = "") String user,
        @RequestParam(value = "request", required = false) String request,
        @RequestParam(value = "start", required = false, defaultValue = "") String start,
        @RequestParam(value = "end", required = false, defaultValue = "") String end, Map<String, Object> map) {
    // временная проверка
    if (user.equals("")) {
        list = reportingServicesService.listReport(request);
    } else {
        list = reportingServicesService.listReport(user, request, start, end);
        columns = reportingServicesService.getColumnNames();
    }

    nameRequest = request;
    // map.put("jiraissue", new jiraissue());
    map.put("reportList", list);
    map.put("lenght", reportingServicesService.getLenghtArrayList(list));
    map.put("columns", columns);
    return "reports";
}
```

DAOImpl Метод выполнения запроса, сам запрос берется из XML

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<? extends Object> listReport(String user, String nameRequest, String start, String end) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(ParserQueryXML.getQueryFromXML(nameRequest))
            .setString("user", user).setString("start", start).setString("end", end).list();
}
```

Сам JSP

```
<c:if test="${!empty reportList}">
<table>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="i" begin = "0" end = "${lenght}">
            <th><spring:message code="${columns[i]}" /></th>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${reportList}" var="report">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://jira.ru/browse/${report[0]}" target="_blank">${report[0]}</a></td>
            <c:forEach var="i" begin = "1" end = "${lenght}">
                <td>${report[i]}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Я мог все проще сделать, указать в ручную поля, но задача не кампилить и вообще не лазить в код. Я вроде все сделал, вот только с полями осталось(((

В дальнейшем все на процедуры переведу, чтобы и не создавать классы сущности